# How to index large number of files contained in a single directory using solr?

Tags: indexing, solr, lucene

I have large number of plain text files in a directory. I want to index them using solr. I used the following command as mentioned in other sources:

`java -Dc=test -Drecursive -Dauto -jar post.jar folder`

but it indexed 0 files. If I have less files then the following works:

`java -Dc=test -Drecursive -Dauto -jar post.jar folder/*`

But in case of large number of files I get this error:

`Argument list too long` .

Note that I am running the command in ubuntu.

Comment: do you use command line only for indexing?

Answer (score 1):

The command line has the limit on the number of the arguments, which you could check by executing `getconf ARG_MAX`

So, number of the files is exceeding this limit and this is the reason why you get this error. You should use `xargs` to overcome this limit.

Example of usage is following (you need to adapt this to your command):

```
find . -name \*xml | xargs java -jar post.jar
```

Comment: To avoid the overhead of starting `post.jar` a lot of times, the `-n` parameter helps. Something like `find folder/ -iname "*.xml" -print0 | xargs -0 -n 100 java -Dc=test -Drecursive -Dauto -jar post.jar` should work.